# Calculate the inverse of a matrix that is a sum of outer products

Tags: matrices

I am trying to find the inverse of matrix in the following form

$\mathbf{R}=\sigma_0\mathbf{I} + \Sigma_{k=1}^{P}\sigma_k\mathbf{d}_k\mathbf{d}_k^H$

where $\mathbf{I}$ is an $M\times M$ identity matrix and $\mathbf{d}_k$ is an $M\times1$ complex column vector. $\sigma_0$ and $\sigma_k$ are real, positive constants.

For $P=1$ and $P=2$, by using matrix inverse lemma, the inverse can be written as a weighted sum of outer products between column vectors $\mathbf{d}_k$. I guess for other values of $P$, it can still be written in such form.

But for $P\ge3$, the calculation is lengthy, tedious and seems impossible.

Is my guess right? If so, what is the general formula for the inverse?

Thank you!

Comment: what are $\sigma_k$? You define $\mathbf I$ but there is no $\mathbf I$ in your formula for $\mathbf R$

Comment: @GiulioR Sorry for the typos. I have edited.

Comment: It feels like it is going to be hard to have a nice closed form unless the $d_k$ are orthogonal, could that be true ?

Comment: @P.Quinton They are linear independent but not orthogonal. $\mathbf{d}_k$ are complex column vectors.